# Solving first order linear pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$xv_x-yv_y=(x-y)\sin(x+y)$$
I am trying to using characteristic method

$\dfrac{dx}{x}=\dfrac{dy}{-y}=\dfrac{dv}{(x-y)(\sin(x+y))}$

From first equality (I mean equation $(1)$ and $(2)$) , we get $xy=c_1$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$ , we get $\dfrac{dx+dy}{x-y}=\dfrac{dv}{(x-y)(\sin(x+y))}$ and so get $v=-\cos(x+y)$

Where Am I Wrong? or How can we solve another method?

Comment: I take my answer back. Your solution is OK, but missing a constant of integration: $v = c_2 - \cos(x +  y)$. Put $c_2$ as an arbitrary function of $c_1$ and you're done!

Comment: Ok thanks, How can we solve it by another method?

Comment: Another method would be the method of green's functions. You have
$$\mathcal{L}[v](x, y)=f(x, y)$$
where
$\mathcal{L}=x\partial_{x}-y\partial_{y}$
The solution may be written as
$$v(x, y)=v_{0}(x, y)+\int\mathcal{G}(x, y, x', y')f(x', y')dx'dy'$$
Where
$$\mathcal{L}[v_{0}](x, y)=0$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}[\mathcal{G}](x, y, x' ,y')=\delta(x-x')\delta(y-y')$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ , letting $x(0)=1$ , we have $x=e^t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^{-t}=\dfrac{y_0}{x}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=(x-y)\sin(x+y)=(e^t-y_0e^{-t})\sin(e^t+y_0e^{-t})$ , letting $v(0)=f(y_0)$ , we have $v(x,y)=f(y_0)-\cos(e^t+y_0e^{-t})=f(xy)-\cos(x+y)$